# Setting a variable to ~/directory doesn't expand

Tags: shell-script, tar

I'm trying to setup a simple backup script with tar as you can see below:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%F_%H-%M`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz
SRCDIR="~/PI/tutos/* ~/scripts/*"
DESTDIR=/media/sf_ubuntuSharedFolder/backups
tar cvpzf $FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

However, the usage of $SRCDIR causes a tar error that I do not have if I just expand it myself.

```
alex@ALeX-VirtualBox:~$ save
tar: ~/PI/tutos/*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ~/scripts/*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong here at using a shell variable? Otherwise, how can I pass a list of folders to tar in a single line?

Comment: Inside double quotes globbing (`*` to list of files) and `~` replacement does not happen.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that `~`-expansion is not performed upon variable expansion (when you refer to that `$SRCDIR` unquoted) nor inside double quotes (when you assign that `SRCDIR` variable).

In leaving `$SRCDIR` unquoted, you're invoking the split+glob operator. That is the string that is stored in that scalar `$SRCDIR` variable (`~/PI/tutos/* ~/scripts/*`) is first split according to `$IFS` (blanks by default), and then each word undergoes globbing, that is are treated as patterns that expand to the list of matching files.

Because `~` is not expanded to your home directory there, that `~` is just treated like any other character, so it's just looking for files in the `~/PI/tutos` directory, where `~` would be a directory in the current directory, which in your case doesn't exist.

Best here would be to make `$SRCDIR` an array and have the globs expanded at the time of the assignment:

```
SRCDIR=(~/PI/tutos/* ~/scripts/*) # ~ and globs expanded at this point
tar cvpzf "$FILENAME" "${SRCDIR[@]}"
```

Note that applying the split+glob operator on `$FILENAME` doesn't make sense, so we're disabling it by quoting `$FILENAME`.

Note that if `~/PI/tutos/*` doesn't match, it will be left as-is, so you'd still get an error from `tar`. To avoid that, you could do:

```
shopt -s nullglob # remove non-matching globs
SRCDIR=(~/PI/tutos/* ~/scripts/*)
if ((${#SRCDIR[@]} != 0)); then
  tar cvpzf "$FILENAME" "${SRCDIR[@]}"
fi
```

You may be tempted to do:

```
SRCDIR="$HOME/PI/tutos/* $HOME/scripts/*"
tar cvpzf "$FILENAME" $SRCDIR
```

As variables (such as `$HOME`) are expanded within double quotes, but I would advise against it as that wouldn't work properly if `$HOME` contains glob characters or characters of `$IFS`.

`~`s are expanded in variable assignments when not quoted and when at the start or following `:` (that's so that it works in assignments of variables like `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`... such as `PATH=~/bin:~/sbin`). So you may be tempted to do:

```
SRCDIR=~/PI/tutos/*:~/scripts/* # ~ (not globs) expanded here
IFS=:
tar cvpzf "$FILENAME" $SRCDIR
```

But that's the same as above, that won't work properly if `$HOME` contains `$IFS` characters (this time `:`, so very unlikely as `/etc/passwd` that defines your home directory is a colon-separated table) or glob characters.

Comment: what exactly does the globbing mean? google translator fails to explain to me

Comment: @burian.vlastimil, that's the expansion of a word like `*.txt` into the list of matching files.

Comment: is that any different than "wildcard" word? thank you, it is much clearer to me now

Comment: @burian.vlastimil, _wildcard_ is the (a) name for the type of pattern that globbing uses to generate the file list. By extension, sometimes _glob_ is also used to designate that type of pattern (even when not used in globbing/filename generation like in `case x in <wildcard-pattern>) ...` or `find . -name '<wildcard-pattern>'`)

Comment: @burian.vlastimil To note: globbing is a technical term, which comes from the POSIX function [`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html), which generates path names from a pattern (with or without wildcards). The name comes from the original UNIX distribution, and is [an abbreviation for "global command"](https://github.com/qrush/unix/blob/c9852189a5533663ea1689fb4f286e4a4ac39403/src/cmd/glob.c#L1).